# JSON to CSV - Write unknown header row just once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small script that converts a JSON object to a dictionary like so:

```
import csv
import json
import sys

jFile = open('path\\to\\jsonFile.json')
j = jFile.read()

class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self, j):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(j)

p = Payload(j)
```

I can then loop through the dictionary to get my key value pairs fairly easily with this:

```
for d in p.Data:
    for key in d:
        #Do Something
```

Writing all of the values to a CSV file is easy as well, but what is the most "Pythonic" way to write the header? I know I could do something like below, but that seems inefficient and not best practice.

```
...
p = Payload(j)
with open('path\\to\\csvFile.csv','w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
    for i, d in enumerate(p.Data):
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys())
        if i == 0:
            w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(d)
```

Is there a way to write the header only once without doing the evaluation each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('path\\to\\csvFile.csv','w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, p.Data[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    for d in p.Data:
        w.writerow(d)
```

Just do it outside the loop.

Comment: Also could do `w.writerows(p.Data)`

Comment: @DrydenLong What type is `p.Data`?  If it's a list, you can do something like `w = csv.DictWriter(f, p.Data[0].keys())`

Comment: That did it! You were correct, p.Data is a list, so establishing an index is what was needed. Do you mind updating your answer with that solution and I'll accept it. Thanks!